# Обновление свойства C#, UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, события, uwp

Нужно добавить событие о том, что элемент внутри класса был изменен.
Variable - экземпляр класса DataItem, в котором содержится последнее прочитанное значение переменной в свойстве Variable.Value(obj). Обновлением данных занят отдельный сервис.
Для того, чтобы вывести полученное значение на экран, используется свойство Value (так как я не могу реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged в библиотеке и привести его к нормальному типу). Соответственно нужно обновить значение свойства Value при изменении Variable.Value методом Update. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при изменении свойства Variable.Value в классе ExperienceValueObservable метод Update вызывался автоматически. Извиняюсь, если не корректно описываю проблему

```
public class ExperienceValueObservable<T> : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Name;
    private T _Value;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { Set(ref _Name, value); }
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { Set(ref _Value, value); }
    }
    public string Dimension { get; set; }
    public DataItem Variable { get; set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Variable.Value != null)
        {
            Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Variable.Value, typeof(T));
        }        
    }
}
    //
// Сводка:
//     Create an instance of a memory block that can be read by using ReadMultipleVars
public class DataItem
{
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Create an instance of DataItem
    public DataItem();

    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Memory area to read
    public DataType DataType { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Type of data to be read (default is bytes)
    public VarType VarType { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Address of memory area to read (example: for DB1 this value is 1, for T45 this
    //     value is 45)
    public int DB { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Address of the first byte to read
    public int StartByteAdr { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Addess of bit to read from StartByteAdr
    public byte BitAdr { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Number of variables to read
    public int Count { get; set; }
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Contains the value of the memory area after the read has been executed
    public object? Value { get; set; }

    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Create an instance of S7.Net.Types.DataItem from the supplied address.
    //
    // Параметры:
    //   address:
    //     The address to create the DataItem for.
    //
    // Возврат:
    //     A new S7.Net.Types.DataItem instance with properties parsed from address.
    //
    // Примечания:
    //     The S7.Net.Types.DataItem.Count property is not parsed from the address.
    public static DataItem FromAddress(string address);
    //
    // Сводка:
    //     Create an instance of S7.Net.Types.DataItem from the supplied address and value.
    //
    // Параметры:
    //   address:
    //     The address to create the DataItem for.
    //
    //   value:
    //     The value to be applied to the DataItem.
    //
    // Возврат:
    //     A new S7.Net.Types.DataItem instance with properties parsed from address and
    //     the supplied value set.
    public static DataItem FromAddressAndValue<T>(string address, T value);
}
```

Comment: Исходя из того кода, что я вижу, эту задачу не решить. Нужно смотреть контекст использования класса с данными, возможно унаследоваться от него и поправить сетиер под свои нужды. Недостаточно информации, а пока ответ - "никак".

Comment: Я не могу переопределить object Value при наследовании, чтобы поправить сеттер

Comment: Ну тогда только исправлять библиотеку, свяжитесь с ее разработчиком.

Comment: Она открытая, проект есть на github. Опыта правки библиотек не было. Надеялся, что может и так получится

Comment: Ну тогда `git clone` ее себе и поправьте, проблемы нет. Вам необязательно реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, вы можете просто добавить кастомный `event`, например `ValueChanged` и вызывать его из сеттера, а из своего кода просто подписаиться на него. Опять же, связаться с разработчиком и рассказать вашу проблему стоит, вдруг он будущие обновления включит исправление для вас?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!